# ASP.NET Core display Action route parameter through AngularJS on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Put simply, I'm trying to have it so that an ID, if passed as an additional `Action` parameter, can be caught by Angular, or passed in as a variable.

As an example, if my Routing was set up as `template: "{action}/{id?}"`, then someone visiting:

`localhost/Waitlist/SpringBash`

(where `Waitlist` is the `action` and `SpringBash` is the `id`)

Could reach a page that says:

```
You're viewing the SpringBash event!

Event1 Name Date
Event2 Name Date
Event3 Name Date
```

I'm handling all of my routes through ASP.Net Core's `MapRoute` and the `Startup` class, and don't intend on converting to an AngularJS routing system.

That said, here's the relevant code I have in `Startup.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "root",
    template: "{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } );
```

My `HomeController.cs` has this ready for a particular page:

```
public IActionResult Waitlist(string eventName)
{
    return View(_context.Waitlist.Where(a => a.Event.Equals(eventName)));
}
```

Under `Views -> Home`, I have my `Waitlist.cshtml`:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/waitlistController.js"></script>
}

<div ng-controller="waitlistController"></div>
```

And in my `waitlistController.js`, I have:

```
wddApp.controller('urlsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    // I don't know what to put here to have access to the {id} parameter of the URL
});
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use `window.location.href`?

https://plnkr.co/edit/z9yRTfYI1nDY5feloDzi?p=preview

```
wddApp.controller('urlsController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    // I don't know what to put here to have access to the {id} parameter of the URL

    var parts = window.location.href.split('/');

    // TODO: probably grab the last one; it's blank for this plunker so 
    // grabbing the second to last one, instead
    $scope.id = parts[parts.length - 2];
});
```

Comment: Nice, I kept trying with `$location` but didn't think of trying `window`. Thanks! :)